# SSIS Package to move files from one folder to another folder in SFTP (WinSCP) (SFTP Task for SSIS)

Tags: ssis, sftp, winscp

I want to move files from one folder to another folder in SFTP (WinSCP). How shall I design the SSIS package?

1. help me to connect WinSCP using SSIS package
2. What shall I use in batch file/custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move files from one folder to another, use the [WinSCP `mv` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_mv):

```
mv /source/folder/* /dest/folder/
```

---

Add this command to WinSCP script file and run WinSCP from the SSIS.

For details, see [SFTP Task for SSIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis).